# R chart.Timeseries in loop not working

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I recently updated to the most recent versions of R and R studio and suddenly chart.TimeSeries from the PerformanceAnalytics package is not working inside a loop.

For example if I highlight the code below in Rstudio and run it , it executes without errors (which you can confirm by checking the value of i = 3 after running) but no plots are produced

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(xts)
ts1 <- xts(1:12, order.by = as.Date("2018-05-01") + (-11:0))
i <- 0
for (i in 1:3) chart.TimeSeries(ts1)
```

However if I replace

```
for (i in 1:3) chart.TimeSeries(ts1)
```

with

```
chart.TimeSeries(ts1)
chart.TimeSeries(ts1)
chart.TimeSeries(ts1)
```

then 3 plots are produced as expected.  Has anyone seen or noted this before or have an explanation for it ?

Update : The same happens if I use `plot.xts` (which is what `chart.TimeSeries` uses under the hood) in place of `chart.TimeSeries`.

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.0                         
year           2018                        
month          04                          
day            23                          
svn rev        74626                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
nickname       Joy in Playing
```

R-Studio verison 1.1.423. PerformanceAnalytics version 1.5.2, xts version 0.10-2

Comment: Have you tried running the code in base R rather than Rstudio?

Comment: Tried the plot.xts version in base R (R Gui), this time R version 3.4.3 (both 32 and 64 bit) but same version of xts.  A graphics device window appears but the inside remains grey, no image. So `for (i in 1:3) {cat(sprintf("i = %d\n", i)) ; plot(1:10, 1:10)}` is fine but `for (i in 1:3) {cat(sprintf("i = %d\n", i)) ; plot.xts(ts1)}` is not.  This is all Windows flavours (7 and 10) btw

Comment: Found a discussion of this issue at the xts github page.  Seems like a known problem  ([link](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/207)) in the current version of xts

Comment: I have had the same issue for a long time on OS X and so far have not found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your example and indeed, my result is the same as yours.
I changed

```
for (i in 1:3) chart.TimeSeries(ts1)
```

to

```
for (i in 1:3) print(PerformanceAnalytics::chart.TimeSeries(ts1))
```

and now all 3 charts are showing properly in my plots panel inside rstudio (I also use up-to-date versions)
Hope this answers your issue.